# What is the best way to get OS specific information in Java?

Tags: java, environment-variables

1. Specifically getting on Windows the "..\Documents & Settings\All Users, basicaly any path that needs the front end to be dynamically derived based on the OS your software is running on. **(Now I need the answer to this)**
2. the current users My Documents  dirctory **(okay this has been answered)** 
   and basicaly any path that needs the front end to be dynamically derived based on the OS your software is running on.

Answer (score 9):

My docs would probably best be handled by accessing:

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Look up the docs on [System.getProperty](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).

Answer (score 3):

Any information you can get about the user's environment can be fetched from

```
System.getProperty("...");
```

For a list of what you can get, take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

I don't think you'll be able to get the path you require (the All Users path) in an OS dependent way.  After all - do other operating systems have an equivalent?  Your best bet is to probably inspect:

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

to see if you are running Windows and then if so use "C:\Documents & Settings\All Users\".

But you'll be better off just constantly using

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

(as mentioned by other people) throughout the application.  Or alternatively, allow the user to specify the directory to store whatever it is you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

> Specifically getting on Windows the "..\Documents & Settings\All Users, basicaly any path that needs the front end to be dynamically derived based on the OS your software is running on. (Now I need the answer to this)

The folders below the All Users dir are variable directories in windows. Details can be found in the document about [KNOWNFOLDERIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in older versions).
Because this values are system dependent Java does not provide a way to access the values.

I think there is in general no equivalent on other operating systems to this windows specific folder. In addition the folder Documents & Settings\All Users is only present in latest windows versions and things are handled differently for e.g Windows 2000 or XP I think.

If you really need this information you should read the microsoft docs and impement a native library or some script invoked by Runtime.exec to provide the information to your java application.